Is there a way to set a 'watchpoint' on an ABAP variable without debugging?
We have an issue where there are runtime errors in our production system almost daily and I can see that this is due to a variable being empty when it should be set. We've tried very hard but cannot recreate the error in any system and it seems to happen randomly 1 in 100 times, I'm thinking due to some kind of timing issue.
This variable is changed in many places including deep within SAP standard functions so I can't add code to every place where it might change. So what I really need is some way to 'watch' the variable so that I can find the specific place where it's being cleared, which will help me find the root cause. This is similar to a watchpoint in the debugger but I want it to happen without debugging.
I was wondering if there's a way to do this in SAP/ABAP? I looked into LOG-POINT but it looks like I'd need to put this in every place where the variable could change but that's not possible.

There's no way.

I concur with Sandra's answer, but this is also not an unreasonable request. The bigger question is: how can we investigate an error like this that only happens once in a while. Only thing I can think of is to add more logging so you might be able to find a pattern for the cases where you do get the runtime error. And I am curious to see what others do in these scenarios, especially where debugging might actually remove the conditions for the error to occur.

The best way is to use dynamic log point in strategics places
